Identify single diode top marking A2, SOT23 (SOT23-3) package
I need to identify a diode (it may be a Schottky) single channel with top marking A2 in SOT23 (SOT23-3) package.


How do you know it's a single schottky?

@areyou please provide dimensions

That solder job looks very peculiar.

If the package is actually SOT-323, it's possibly a MMBD4148W/BAS16W diode.

The datasheet image is from JSCJ, but there are many manufacturers with different markings. Closest picture I could find doesn't state the manufacturer, but is also labeled MMBD4148W.

(source: alibaba.com)

Can be HSMS-2802 Schottky diodes. The D2 marking next to the chip indicated it is a diode IC. You can check with a multimeter to see if the forward bias is less than the usual diode.
If it is Schottky diode, then A2 marking means it is dual type with the following configuration.

